# Array Formula alternative solution with SumIF - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, linechart, sumifs

I have data in the below format:
[image]

The "Date" Column is a sequence of dates generated using the formula:

```
=sequence(datedif(TODAY(),MAX(D2:D),"D")+2,1,TODAY(),Date(0,1,0))
```

The "Avg. Mnthly Hrs" is calculated against each Date value as below:

```
=SUMIF(D:D,">="&E2,C:C)
```

The issue here is, whenever I have a new Project, where the "Exp. Project End Date" is let's say 5/31/2045, the Date column is extended automatically using the sequence formula and generates values in days until that day but the "Avg. Mnthly Hrs" formula doesn't calculate the new values (like in Array Formula).
[image]

The ArrayFormula doesn't work with SumIF formula. Is there any similar alternative so that the "Avg. Monthly Hrs" formula extends automatically for new values in Date column.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: It looks to me like "Mike Steelson" has offered a working solution below. But I'm left wondering about your date-generating SEQUENCE formula. First, what do you believe the final parameter `DATE(0,30,0)` is doing or is supposed to do? Second, is it a practical need to know your standing on remaining average monthly hours *every day* (and for the next 23 years at that)? I can't help but think you actually need (or maybe even wanted) to only list *month ends* in Col E given all the factors, including that your Col-D dates are all month ends.

Answer (score 1):

In F2, try

```
=arrayformula(if(E2:E="",,SUMIF(D:D,">="&E2:E,C:C)))
```